# Parse rules CF-grammar using Regular Expressions (how using templates)

Tags: c++, regex, grammar, boost-regex

I have CF-grammar. It rules is as follows:

> S->a|AS
>
> A->AB|a|b
>
> B->b

I want to parse these rules using Regular Expressions.

My Regular Expression:

> \b([A-Z])->(?:([A-Za-z]+)\|?)+

For: "A->AB|a|b" result:

> 0: A->AB|a|b
>
> 1: A
>
> 2: b

but I whant this:

> 0: A->AB|a|b
>
> 1: A
>
> 2: AB
>
> 3: a
>
> 4: b

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Comment: I would use "[A-Za-z]+", but that's not what I want

Answer (score 0):

Regular Expressions aren't sufficiently powerful for the task, but are used for instance in EBFN to enhance expressiveness of the grammar. You could consider a topdown parser (shaped via recursive calls) to parse your input. That's easy to implement in all languages that allows mutually recursive calls. It requires a grammar with some restrictions (see Wikipedia about this, if you are interested). At first glance your grammar should be LL(1), i.e. requires 1 token lookahead.

Answer (score 0):

You could just split every rule with `->|\|` to get the desired list.

Comment: I'm not fluent in C++/boost, but I can show you a Perl example: `say join "\n", split /->|\|/, "A->AB|a|b";`. Related boost links http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/regex/doc/regex_split.html and http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_31_0/libs/regex/doc/regex_token_iterator.html

Comment: Use "->" and "|" as separators in Split?

Comment: Yes, `->|\|` is a regex (not the formal kind) that matches either a `->` or `|`.

Comment: If so, it does not fit. Because it will work as regex "[A-Za-z]+". I want, that a regular expression sets whether it's a rule. And divided into parts.